# get local time of new zealand using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get local time of newzealand using node.js . in node red

please see the resources below:

link: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-time

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/time

Answer (score -1):

Based on the tz database on wikipedia, you want to use this timezone:

```
Pacific/Auckland
```

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones